# Катамит, синонимы, жен. род

Tags: синонимы

Да простит меня господь бог всемогущий за такой пикантный вопрос, но существует ли синоним этого слова, характеризующий молодую особу женского пола (термины связанные с оказанием половых контактов за деньги не подходят по определению)? Слово наложница представляется наиболее подходящим, однако не корректным, может, кто-нибудь знает? (Предвкушая различные возгласы со стороны, насчёт тактичности задаваемого, сразу заявлю - вопрос для общего развития).

Comment: У него не только синонимы существуют - у него прямой перевод существует :>
"Котик мой", kata mite :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя **Лолита** уже давно стало нарицательным. Из того же Набокова можно вспомнить слово "**нимфетка**".

Comment: Как вариант. Природа ведь не терпит пустоты.